# Getting a Canon LiDE 200 to work

Tags: drivers, canon

I have this Canon LiDE 200 but simple scan cannot use it properly. With the new sane-backend from rober-ancell's ppa the scanner head at least moves a little, but simple-scan simply fails telling me that the scanning fails in a red banner below the menu bar.

Is there some way to get it to work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same error as the original poster, which led me here.

The `40-libsane.rules` file and the sane compatibility list suggested it should *"just work"*, so I tinkered a bit and found that if you change the setting in *Simple Scan* preferences called `Scan Side` and set it to `Back` (rather than the default `Front and Back`), all is good.

Comment: Wow, that feels like vodoo :-). I think I'll have to experiment with the gamma options of `scanimage` until the scans look good.

Answer (score 4):

First I followed the recommendations:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:robert-ancell/sane-backends
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libsane libsane-extras sane-utils
```

Then I installed xsane and finally my Canoscan Lide 200 started to work.

Comment: Yes, xsane works, simple-scan not for some reason.

Comment: "Then I installed xsane" => `sudo apt-get install xsane`

Answer (score 2):

This last part of the forum entry is what I had to do to get my scanner working

If scanning doesn't work as a regular user, continue with step 3.

3) To allow us to scan as a regular user, we need to modify the USB permissions for the scanner, so follow step 5 from
Quote:
Originally Posted by dli8ilb
Now everything is installed, but you still won't be able to scan (except as root) until you set up some permissions.

5) You need to edit a file, but you need to be root to edit it, so:

```
gksu gedit /lib/udev/rules.d/40-libsane.rules
```

and add the following 2 lines:

```
# Canon CanoScan Lide 200
ATTRS{idVendor}=="04a9", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1905", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"
```

save the file, exit gedit, exit terminal, reboot, and...

My question about this is when a scanner driver is installed why is this file not automatically updated?

Comment: That file already contains these these lines on my computer. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Just had some trouble getting the LiDE 200 working in Simple Scan running Precise.

All I did was change **Scan Side** to "**Back**" in **Simple Scan Preferences**, add myself to the `saned` group, log out/in and voilà!

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I got exactly the same message on Natty. I installed the PPA: nothing. Running as root: nothing. Then I thought about using xsane so I did a: sudo aptitude install xsane

Then used simple-scan and it worked :s
Hope this also helps for you!

Comment: This sounds strange, but I will give it a try.

Comment: No, it does not work :-/

Comment: xsane itself seems to work, but simple-scan still fails.

Answer (score 0):

See this [response](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10526638&postcount=31) on the Ubuntu forums. I did something similar for my LiDE 100

Comment: Please also include the solution. If the forum goes down for maintenance or for good due to an alien invasion, your answer becomes useless. ;-) On a side note: Robert Ancell is a Canonical employee - just to raise confidence that this PPA is legit.

Comment: It does recognize the scanner now, and when I clicked “scan”, I heard some noise, but then it failed: `** (simple-scan:6137): WARNING **: Unable to start device: Error during device I/O`

Comment: @queueoverflow: Is the scanner unlocked (should have a switch somewhere)?

Comment: @htorque: It is unlocked, I used it with Mac OS X just on the same day, the scanner itself seems to work fine.

Comment: The thing is, that it fails consistently on the first scan, but works on every consecutive scan. I wrote a little script that just runs it again if it fails.